# How to offer a file compressed as download via spring @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a servlet that offers a `CSV` file for download:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public FileSystemResource getFile() {
        return new FileSystemResource("c:\file.csv"); 
    }
}
```

This works just fine.

Question: how can I offer this file as compressed file? (zip, gzip, tar doesn't matter)?

Comment: Do you want to create a zip file on the server or use the "on the fly gzip compression" between webserver and client-browser?

Comment: I want to create a compressed file (from the uncompressed local file). If it's `zip` or `gzip` doesn't matter.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113345/compress-dynamic-content-to-servletoutputstream . The same trick would work with a plain controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113345/compress-dynamic-content-to-servletoutputstream) (for a plain `Servlet`), you can also do the same with a Spring MVC based controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(OutputStream out) {
    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("c:\file.csv"); 
    try (ZipOutputStream zippedOut = new ZipOutputStream(out)) {
        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(resource.getName());
        // Configure the zip entry, the properties of the file
        e.setSize(resource.contentLength());
        e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // etc.
        zippedOut.putNextEntry(e);
        // And the content of the resource:
        StreamUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), zippedOut);
        zippedOut.closeEntry();
        zippedOut.finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something with Exception
    }        
}
```

You created a `ZipOutputStream` based on the responses `OutputStream` (which you can simply have injected into the method). Then create an entry for the zipped out stream and write it.

Instead of the `OutputStream` you could also wire the `HttpServletResponse` so that you would be able to set the name of the file and the content type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) {
    FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("c:\file.csv"); 
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");

    try (ZipOutputStream zippedOut = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream())) {
        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(resource.getName());
        // Configure the zip entry, the properties of the file
        e.setSize(resource.contentLength());
        e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // etc.
        zippedOut.putNextEntry(e);
        // And the content of the resource:
        StreamUtils.copy(resource.getInputStream(), zippedOut);
        zippedOut.closeEntry();
        zippedOut.finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something with Exception
    }        
}
```

Comment: What would the return type of the method be? `ZipOutputStream`? Would the same be possible with `GZIPOutputStream`?

Comment: I tried `return zippedOUt`, but gave me: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`. When adding `produces = "application/zip"`, it results in `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`.

Comment: There would be no return... Hence the `void`, I wrote it like that for a reason!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. Could I also set the target filename (like `file.csv.zip`) into the `OutputStream`? I didn't know it's possible to just use the `OutputStream` as a method parameter. A very keen solution, ty!

Comment: See that last part of the question... I covered that already briefly (modified it to include a sample as well).

Comment: Solved! See this page if you need generic solution for any case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75595252/15959923

Answer (score 0):

Untested but something like that should work:

```
final Path zipTmpPath = Paths.get("C:/file.csv.zip");
final ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipTmpPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));
final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("file.csv");
zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
Path csvPath = Paths.get("C:/file.csv");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(csvPath);
for(String line : lines)
{
    for(char c : line.toCharArray())
    {
        zipOut.write(c);
    }
}
zipOut.flush();
zipOut.close();
return new FileSystemResource("C:/file.csv.zip");
```

Comment: I thought there could be a simpler way than just having to create an additional local file. Eg returning a csv file is a simple as returning a `FileSystemResource` with spring. Thought there might be also something for compression. ot: I have 27 gold points though not 11k ;)

Comment: oh ... sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score -3):

use this :

@RequestMapping(value = "/zip", produces="application/zip")

This may solve your issue

Comment: ... why on earth does everyone suddenly think that spring is a no-brain framework with magic superpowers?? Spring doesnt compress automatically - there **may** be some sort of plugin or special configuration for that but ....